# Function in useEffect hook is not running

Tags: node.js, reactjs, use-effect, react-context

For past two days I was struggling with problem that on page reload reactJS/NodeJS app goes to login page. I use jwt authentication. On each page I have `loadUser` function in `useEffect`
There is function:

```
const loadUser = async () => {
    if (localStorage.token) {
      setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
    }

    try {
      const res = await axios.get("/api/auth");
      dispatch({ type: USER_LOADED, payload: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({ type: AUTH_ERROR });
    }
  };

// USER_LOADED 

case USER_LOADED:
  return {
    ...state,
    isAuthenticated: true,
    loading: false,
    user: action.payload,
    loaded: true,
  };
```

On page reload application goes to login page and sets initial state. Looks like the function is not running and I can't understand why?

Any ideas?

Comment: make sure your axios.get requires the leading backslash.. depending on your api

Comment: url is fine. because this function works from login page to home page, but then on reload it's not working..state is not setted up and it just go to login page..other function in useefect works.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems not synchronized. Could you show the hook and the redirection + storage of the auth state locally.

I personally have used cookies for storage purpose of token locally. I called my api with credentials:"include". But not on every page, just the main page as its a React Application so all components in the end merge and show at let's say a dashboard.
And simple if the api returned true i set the local authorized state variable to true.
And below rendered the dashboard, the else statement means the api is still being called (the internet is slow etc).

{
fetch(`${pusherConfig.API_URL}/admin/api/dashboard`, {
method: "GET",
credentials: "include",
})
.then((res) => res.text())
.then((res) => setAuthState({ authorized: 1 }));
}

{authorized ? ( DashboardComponent /> ) : (

Protected Route! authenticating.../p> )}

and on the main login page also same setup as above. (Since its an entire different page)

{logined ? LoginComponent /> : DashboardComponent />}

Comment: I found mistake messed up with PrivateRoute